# Can speakers be boosted?

Tags: speakers, sound

I have a very basic understanding of electronics as I'm a computer student and we only studied into to electronics.So I have a bunch of headphones lying around and there are atleast 5-6 having around 10-12 speakers in them and none of them is damaged.So I was thinking of making a DIY speakers box and I was thinking as if I could add all speakers from headphones because they have a limited sound.So are they limited to that sound or thats there limit.Any way I could boost their sound for a speaker??

Comment: As Dave says - could be done but needs to be done properly and liable to not be worth the effort. Headphones are liable to be rated at < 1 Watt input ( maybe <<) and unlikely to produce useful volume in general application at their max rated power. Sadly.

Answer (score 4):

The amount (and quality) sound produced by a transducer is limited by its physical construction — its area, its range of motion, and its ability to handle the electrical power (heat).

It is possible to create useful speakers from large arrays of small transducers, but you still need to operate each transducer within its capabilities. Indeed, such arrays have some very useful properties, but you have to know exactly what you're doing, both acoustically and electronically.

For example, I saw a technical presentation on [this product](http://www.audioartistry.com/products_CBT.htm) a few years ago at a local AES meeting. The engineering is sound, and the sound was quite impressive.

Comment: I hadn't known that some of it had been declassified. Nice.